# Weighted percentages by group in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, weighted-average

I'm stumped on the following as I'm trying to display an accurate weighted percentage in group footer using the following formula which seems to work for the grand total only:

((Sum(ProductionCost)-Sum(ActualCost)) / Sum(ProductionCost)) * 100

Is there a way on each group footer section to indicate this formula to work within current group at least so I don't have to tediously do different formulas for every possible group?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to the `Sum()` function controls the group level the sum works over. See [the documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/topic/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic531.html) for more info.

You can also create a straight summary instead of a formula. Go to "Insert" → "Summary" → select the field you want to summarize and select the `Sum` function → at the bottom of the window you'll see options for which group level to place the summary and also a check box that will display it as a percentage of another summary.